Number grid dance
Place numbers 1, 2 and 3 somewhere on a grid. If two numbers A and B are adjacent, in any of 8 directions, then their sum A+B can be added to an adjacent empty cell along the same direction. In the following example you can add numbers A+B, A+C and B+C.

You must add consecutive and distinct numbers 4, 5, 6 and so on. What is the largest number you can add?

Are duplicates allowed, or must we have exactly one of each number?

You mean that we have to produce sums of two adjacent numbers, such that the first sum is $4$, the second is $5$, and so forth, right?

No duplicates allowed (added distinct).

@AlexRavsky that's correct

Related: https://oeis.org/A350627

Must A+B be adjacent to A or B, or can it be added to any empty cell along the same direction?

@noedne must be adjacent

My best answer is ${}{}$

 13


 
  C  8
   9 7 2
    3145
   A 6 B
  D
 


Edit: The first answer applies to the conditions as were stated originally, the second still applies to the updated version.
If I've understood the rules correctly, I think I can get to 16 as follows

 
     E
  9 7 2
  53148C
  A 6 B G
 D     F
 

Previous answer

 13

As follows

 
 C   8
  915
   3 D
  246A
   7
   B
 


I believe your original answer is correct and optimal by computer aided search. Your update looks to have a misplaced 5.

@kagami I believe Hexomino is interpreting "next empty cell" to allow placing the sum on either end of the current line. (Also affects 8 and G) The  wording has since been changed to disallow this.

@kagami Do you happen to know the answer to the question as originally stated (possibly via computer)? I managed to get to 16 but it felt like 17 or 18 should be possible with some cleverness.

@hexomino If I understand the rules as they were originally written, here are the coordinates for 23 placements: [(0, 0), (-2, -1), (1, 0), (-1, 0), (2, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1), (3, 0), (2, -1), (1, 2), (1, -2), (-1, 2), (-2, 0), (2, -2), (-2, -2), (-3, -2), (-3, 0), (-2, 1), (-1, -2), (4, 1), (-4, 1), (2, -3), (2, 1)]

@kagami wow, that's a great example, was this the max you were able to find?

Looks like 23 is optimal.
